# Trying to subtract to date cells based on criteria add

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Im trying to subtract todays date (cell A) from an original incident date (cell B) to come up with days outstanding but when the original incident date = sunday (I used the weekday function to come up with #7 (cell C) I need to add 1 day to the outstanding total... I tried to use IF, Sumif and cant get it to work.

Comment: By default, Weekday returns 1 for Sunday, not 7.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
=DAYS(B1, A1) + IF(WEEKDAY(B1) = 7, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordan..Would it be  a different answer for office 365 excel version. I am trying to help someone on excel 2013 but I have office 365 version... the answer I received was a date???

Comment: No, same answer will work.  If you see a Date, Format the Cell as General or Number, instead of Date.

Comment: Great this was perfect help... Thanks Gordon

Comment: got a little more complicated Gordon... =DAYS(N3, B3)+IF(WEEKDAY(B3)=7, IF(K3="DETAINED", 2))  So this was adding 2 to the calculation but if I want to subtract 2 it does not work??? I put =DAYS(N3, B3)+IF(WEEKDAY(B3)=7, IF(K3="DETAINED", -2)) Is there a special way to subtract

Comment: @Sly, like this:  =DAYS(N3, B3) - IF(WEEKDAY(B3)=7, IF(K3="DETAINED", 2))